# How to Exit Debug Mode When Browser Closed?

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio-2012, iis-express

when i debug my ASP.NET application / website in visual studio ,  after closing browser window ,debugging not stop and IIS Express Still working.
how can i stop debugging after close browser
i am develop my program in visual studio 2012 SP1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Closing the browser window in Visual Studio 2012 will detach the debugger.  If the ASP.NET development [web] server is still running after you do that, you can always right click on it in the system tray and select "stop".

Comment: i know..but i want to detach debugger and terminate IIS  when i close browser

Comment: That is what happens when you close the browser that has the same PID that is attached to the debugger.